# How can I get EasySound (a .wav player) to work in my code?

Tags: java, audio

I am creating a fortune teller program for my AP ComSci course, but I cannot get ping.wav to work according to the instructions.

Instructions: Edit fortuneTeller.java to randomly give back a fortune an play ping.wav when the "Next" button is pressed. Add EasyClasses.jar as a required library.

Here is my code so far:

```
// Fortune Teller

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class FortuneTeller extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

//  private static final EasySound ding = new EasySound("ding.wav");

  private String[] fortune = {"You will find a penny", "You like cheese", "You will get a car","You will get ebola",
    "You will becomea DOTA pro"};

  private JTextField display;

  public FortuneTeller()
  {
    super("Fortune Teller");

    display = new JTextField("  Press \"Next\" to see your fortune...", 25);
    display.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    display.setEditable(false);

    JButton go = new JButton("Next");
    go.addActionListener(this);

    Container c = getContentPane();
    c.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    c.add(display);
    c.add(go);
  }

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {
    // Pick and display a random fortune:

    int r = (int)(Math.random() * 5);

    String f = fortune[r];

    display.setText("  " + f );
//    ding.play();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    JFrame window = new FortuneTeller();
    window.setBounds(300, 300, 300, 100);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setResizable(false);
    window.setVisible(true); 
  }
}
```

The code returns a fortune with the ping.wav commented out, but when I try to uncomment this, I get an error saying "EasySound cannot be resolved to a type". I have other codes using EasySound and do not get this error. I have added EasyClasses.jar to the project folder along with ping.wav. How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have added EasyClasses.jar to the project folder along with ping.wav

Just adding the jar to the project folder is not enough. You have to import it to your classes too.

As you have imported `import javax.swing.JButton; import java.awt.Color;` you have to import the `EasyClasses`.

Eg: `import com.a.b.EasyClasses;` Here com, a, and b are the package names and you are importing the `EasyClasses.java` to the project which is inside those packages in the `jar` file.